# transfer data from hd via usb

Tags: backup

My Latitude D420 has the following Hard Drive, 060G, Parallel Advanced Technology Attachment, 5MM, 4.2K, T030. Which usb device would work to move the data to the pc? the laptop is DEAD. I am hoping to salvage the data.

System config:

```
1   TF868   ASSEMBLY..., BASE (ASSEMBLY OR GROUP)..., SINGLE CORE YONAH..., 1.2, D420
0   01323   INFORMATION..., NO ITEM
1   DF771   CORD..., Power, 125, 1M, C7, 2P Dual, United States
1   YK181   Guide, Product, Information Client, DAO/BCC
1   HN662   Assembly, Adapter, Alternating Current, 65W, Cost Reduced, Hipro2P
1   KH384   Keyboard, 84, United States England, Dual Pointing, D420
1   HJ178   Cable, Flexible Printed Circuit, Hard Drive, Toshiba D420
1   TH743   Hard Drive, 060G, Parallel Advanced Technology Attachment, 5MM, 4.2K, T030
1   RX073   Kit, Software, Overpack, WXPPSP2 Compact Diskette W Documentation, English
1   JG768   Battery, Primary, 68WH, 9C Lithium, Samsung Power Division
1   C831D   Kit, Software, Powerdvd, 7.0 Digital Video Disk Drive 7.0-02
1   PC559   Card, Wireless, Minicard, DW1390 Broadcom Corporation
1   Y9525   Dual In-line Memory Module 512MB, 667, 64X64, 8K, 200
1   TW039   Assembly, DVD+/-RW..., D Module Non-Factory Installed, Hitachi LG Data Storage
1   KG118   Assembly, Cover, Hinge, Plastic Latitude, D420
1   GJ277   Bracket, Rubber, Hard Drive Notebook, Toshiba, D420
```

Thanks

Comment: Huh?  Where is your data currently?  Is "the pc" the Latitude or a different computer?

Comment: on that hardrive, however the laptop is not working anymore :(

Comment: Huh? I need to buy some kind of a device to be able to attach the hard-drive. hence I need some sort of USB Enclosure compatible with my drive...

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, go to eBay and just look for the cheapest 2.5" laptop hard drive caddy as this is all you need... You haven't really given enough details but as you said 4.2k, I am guessing it is old and IDE.

You can probably pick one up for less than £5 including shipping, and it should do the job for you.

It will come up on your pc as a new drive letter and you can transfer files across. This is of course, assuming the problem with the laptop is not hard drive related.

If it is newer and SATA, you can plug it straight into any desktop SATA port.

Answer (score 0):

Dell uses normal 2.5in hard drives. However sometimes Dell uses an adopter attached to the hard drive. The adopter "should" be able to be taken off. Don't force it but it should just slide off. After the adopter is taken off, then all you would need is IDE or SATA enclosure depending on what type of connection the hard drive uses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one of these [USB to SATA/IDE adapters](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2477926&CatId=3770), they are a great resource and fit a multitude of drives:

[image]